# jQuery get Object Tag's true width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have `<object>` tag inside a `<div>`. I've been getting around to get the "width" of the `<object>` tag, which has 73 px each. The problem is it isn't returning the true width of `<object>` tag with jQuery's `width()` method.

Here is my code.

```
<!-- This object has 73 px height -->
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/my-logo.svg" class="slashes"></object>

console.log($('.slashes').width()); // returns 300 instead of 73
```

How do I get the true width of object element?

Comment: Is it incorrect with .css('width'), too?

Comment: It returns `"73px"` for now. Thanks. Do you know why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: Not sure, haven't really followed jQuery lately. There are some factors that can affect accuracy of getting dimensions of elements. I guess both use getComputedStyle() internally (or maybe .width() not?) and it seems css() is remains more accurate.

Comment: `width()`, `outerWidth()`, `outerWidth(true)` these are available too, sometime the element has `padding`, `margin` that will not calculated by `width()` so based on your need use on of those.

Comment: @ColinCline The object tag or it's parent doesn't have margin or padding though.

Comment: `The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.` reference:- https://prnt.sc/hmaos7

Comment: how about use javascript dom function ? `$('.slashes')[0].getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: @LinYuan Same. `$('.slashes')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width` is returning 300.